# Library Cannot resolve method in TrueTime library

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, ntp

I'm trying to use the relatively new TrueTime library at https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android.

As instructed, I put the following in the build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:1.5'
}
```

Then in the Activity, I import it with:

```
import com.instacart.library.truetime.extensionrx.TrueTimeRx;
```

and invoke it with:

```
TrueTimeRx.build().initializeRx("time.apple.com")
```

except "initializeRx" is red and hover tip says "Cannot invoke method 'initializeRx(java.lang.String)'"

The 'initialize()' and other methods are shown as available when I type "TrueTimeRx.build()." so why isn't initializeRx?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using an older version of **TrueTime** library. Its documentation configures version 1.5, but the [latest one is 2.0](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android/tree/2.0).

So, change your dependency to:

```
compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:2.0'
```

> **Remember:** every time you need to use a library hosted at GitHub, check
>   the branch combobox and look forward the latest tag version.

Comment: So obvious...and embarrassing! Thanks.

Comment: Come on, we always trust the docs are ok, but they aren't. It happens. :)